# Countdown time in background with progress bar and after countdown i want to disable a button in android studio java

Tags: android-studio

Countdown time in background with progress bar and after countdown i want to disable a button. Please provide code in java. i am a beginner. please explain the code too please.

i search on Youtube and gooole but there is nothing